# Magento 2 - change mobile navigation text color

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

How can i change the mobile navigation text color in .less file? Which variable is this?

Answer (score 1):

Quick tip to answer your question:

If you are using **chrome**:

**Step 1:** press **F12** then click on the mobile/tablet icon on the top left corner, or press **CTRL + SHIFT + M** to switch to mobile view.

**Step 2:**  Click on the mouse arrow icon next to the mobile/tablet icon or press **CTRL + SHIFT + C**, and select the element you want to modify.

At this point the browser will highlight the selected element, so you can copy it's class name.